# Vaadin 6.8.1 Horizontal Split Panel Height/Scroll issue

Tags: java, layout, drag-and-drop, scroll, vaadin

I have a horizontal split panel issue on vaadin. It's all about DnDWrapper. After I drag the picture left to right a strange scrollbar appears at the second container.

[image]

[And please more info/code sample examine here](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/4259124)

Comment: After dropping ` whichLayout.addComponent( tmpDragArea );` can you not resize `whichLayout`

Comment: actually it's not resizing after drop ?! I'm confused

Comment: Sorry I am new to vaadin, but I was meaning to manually resize or fire and repaint event

Comment: hmm, i see. I will  try something as you mentioned and let you know.

Comment: i tried to repaint horizontalsplit panel on drop event with :   horizontalSplitPanel.setSizeUndefined();
                horizontalSplitPanel.setSizeFull();

Comment: It slightly worked but not working when i drag pic to first column of right side. After that it's working..interesting.. On every first column it's not working, on second and third columns it's working..

Comment: cool - type of (I guess)

Comment: actually still need a better solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an empty label to left side for every added object to right resolved the issue. And after that i called:

```
horizontalSplitPanel.requestRepaintAll();
```